Simple Email Manager for incoming email + storing sent email - Not for sending, not for composing, not for tracking, not for mass-mailing
TL;DR
I want to convert email-reading (typically done in an IMAP) into a document-access system (with ACL, etc.)
Purpose
To manage the stored emails for a team about 50 people dealing with ~25 new emails sent/received per day, about 500.000 emails per year:
Types of emails:

Emails with clients, quotation phase (pre-payment)
Emails with clients, service phase (post-payment)
Emails with providers
Emails with partners
Emails with shareholders of the company
Emails between the team
Emails gotten from bots/alert systems
Many more

In this company the "emails sent/received" constitute a "proof of facts" because anything offered to a customer via human-hand-made-email is legally binding and any request made via human-created emails to the providers are also binding and affecting the clients.
There are a bunch of email addresses and also some aliases. Customers and providers do write to NAMED emails (like john.doe@example.com) and never to generic emails (like sales@example.com).
I don't need to send
Any sending will be done by the proper MUA and/or SMTP.
I'm not concerned in "sending" at all, but to "how to keep track of all things, received and send".
For this exercice we will assume any sent email is "stored in the system" as well.
Current setup
The team is organized in units of work. Say 10 units of 5 people each.
Up to now, we go with IMAP servers, but this does not meet certain needs. Those are some limitations we find:

There's not a common folder structure. Even if we want to force one, each user may manage their IMAP folders as they want.
It depends on the user to process their inbox to get some alerts about "hey, this was not for me"
If a team member gets ill or on vacation, the other tem members need his password to access his history, and surprisingly, finds everything organized in some other type of organization.
Depending on the user's client (MUA), they may set different settings to control the deletions or archiving of the server.
This last thing is specially critical when accessing "generic addresses" like "booking@xxx" where multiple users enter via multiple MUAs. For example one using Thunderbird may have "when sending an email set it in the inbox" while another "when sending an email put it in sent messages".
Users may delete emails.
We make a lot of references to the Message-Id header to keep track of "we said this in this email" but it turns difficult to make a search by that field in the whole company.
Depending on the configuration of that user, senders of the received may track when the user opens the email.

Here's what should happen

Email that enters into the servers, email that is hard-stored and never can be deleted. In the case of deletion-request (for example some credentials slipped-in) the deletion must only be done by the admins or undergo a process.
Each employee may access only his "email manager account" which typically will grant access to "his email account" + "any general purpose addresses assigned to that employee".
If Peter peter@example.com gets ill then the sub-team manager (the one managing the group of 5 members of that team) may assign that Mary will temprarily see <mary@...> and <peter@...> but still will only be for reading, she only will write as mary.
When Peter recovers and comes back to the office, Mary will be dropped the access to <peter@...>
If the mini-team boss does not have anyone who to assign the email from peter, he may agree with another boss of another team to grant access to peter@ from a member of another team.
All emails should be taggable with multi-faceted classification, like for example [invoice] + [provider] + [Provider XXX] + [Service YYY] + ...
All emails in the company should be searchable my Message-Id (this does not mean "anyone" can do the search)
All emails in the company should be searchable by free text (this does not mean "anyone" can do the search)
Classification into "folders" is just "a view" for a specific user that does not really "move" the email in the server.
Browsability should be done via tags.
Opening the email should be untrackable (ie: disable image loading, etc.)
Tagging should be an hybrid of using pre-defined tags and proposing new tags.

In short
We need to add a) integrity, b) searchability/findability and c) access rules to the email system so "anyone can access anything needed but no one can access anything not needed + internal tracking of access" + guarrantee emails are 100% immutables.

It should work as an append-only system where each incoming email is written to a W.O.R.M. as is (original RAW text from the server, typically the .eml file).
After writing the email to the WORM it gets "indexed" by the metadata inside itself (like from: to: subject: date: message-id: etc.)
Email is auto-tagged with data in the index, like "from" and potentially "recognized patterns".
After indexed "by the metadata" it's readable by any user with access to the "to/cc" of the email.
That user may additionally tag the email with "standardized tags".

Implement by myself?
I'm tempted to do a software by myself.
But I wonder if it already exists something to solve this.
If I did it, i'd do it with 3 components:

RECEIVER + BUCKET:

Email MX reception server, possibly based on a postfix o any starndard system that receives "any" email and triggers an event "email received" to the indexer.
Storage can be filesystem all emails in a single folder.
If local storage, to avoid running out of inodes, some storage hashing algorithm could be applied but that is tech-requirements, really not anything semantic.
Maybe supporting a clod like S3 where you don't run into the "inode problem" and you may virtually have an infinite number of objects in the bucket.
At the end we have some sort of key-value here: Given a key I may retrieve the whole email.


INDEXER:

When the "email received" event triggers, the indexer proceeds to read the email and build some metadata.
Metadata can be stored in a different media, like on top of a MySQL
When the email is properly indexed, it's placed "to the disposition of the appropriate readers".


READER:

This could be via web or even it could be an IMAP server so the users can use their preferred user agent to read the email.
When the MUA connects to this reader, it determines what emails this user has access to, based on the metadata written by the indexer. The reader then lists the emails based on the browsing criteria.
This would also log reading access. If peter@ is ill and mary@ temporarily has access to peter's 3.000 emails it does not mean mary opens those 3k emails. Maybe she opens 30 units of email to be read. Then peter back in the office will see "mary opened this email on X day" if configured so.



CQRS+ES?
This would work mainly like a CQRS+ES system where the receiver is the "write side" bound to the "events" of "email received", the indexer is the "projector" which is run behind the scenes, asynchronously, upon an event is received, and the reader which responds to the "read model" (ie: how the user would like to view the information).
A little bit this project is like converting CRUD-emails to CQRS/ES-emails.
Objective requirements

Open source
Dockerizable

Investigation so far
I initially thought answers to this question would address my concern, but that is a slightly different approach.
They are asking for a full-suite (composing, emailing lists, etc.) - My requirements are not those.
